# Finding the center, radius of a circle when there is a constant in front of the variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

$$4x^2+(y-2)^2 = 4$$

How to find the center and radius of a circle when there is a constant in front of the variables?

Comment: This wouldn't be a circle. EDIT: To be even clearer, this is the equation for an ellipse.

Comment: thanks for clearing doubts

Answer (score 2):

As Eevee Trainer commented, this is an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

You can rewrite the equation as $$\frac{(x-0)^2}{1^2} + \frac{(y-2)^2}{2^2} = 1$$

which suggests that

- the centre of the ellipse is at $(0,2)$
- the [semi-minor axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes) (an equivalent of the radius) parallel to the $x$-axis is $1$
- the semi-major axis (the other equivalent of the radius) parallel to the $y$-axis is $2$

Comment: I'd say "shows" instead of "suggests".

Comment: @NickD - you may be correct, but I did not really want to dig deeper in issues like $1 \lt 2$ deciding which of the axes were major or minor